# Filter Array by last index of unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an on change method that is doing a series of caluculations for various users dividing a total amount into partials and attaching it to their name.

```
    {payment.caseWorkers.map((worker) => (
          <li>
            {worker.name}:{worker.role}{" "}
            <input
              type='text'
              name={worker.name}
              placeHolder='Enter Percent Split'
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
```

```
  const onChange = (e) => {

    setSplit([
      ...split,
      {
        [e.target.name]: 0.01 * payment.paymentAmount * e.target.value * 0.2,
      },
    ]);
  };
```

creates

```
[{mickey gray: 5}, {mickey gray: 50}, {mickey gray : 500}, {steve smith: 5}, {steve smith: 50}, {steve smith: 500}]
```

i need

```
[{mickey gray: 500}, {steve smith: 500}]
```

by last index in case someone puts one too many zeros

e.target.name is the username
e.target.value is the amount they enter

so they create every time they enter a new array object where ideally the last entry is the correct number for that user.

so i need to create a filter that takes the last index of each unique [e.target.name].

i have tried the (a,x,i) x=> indexOf(a) === i logic, i have tried looping through object.keys in a foreach none of these approaches work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your actual problem.

Comment: I think what you need is `findLastIndex()`, but this function doesn't exist. You can reverse the array and then use the `findIndex()` logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not all that elegant but you could do it like below.

```js
var input = [{"mickey gray": 5}, {"mickey gray": 50}, {"mickey gray" : 500}, {"steve smith": 5}, {"steve smith": 50}, {"steve smith": 500}];

// basically - groupby key
var intermediate = input.reduce( (acc,i) => {
   Object.keys(i).forEach( key => acc.hasOwnProperty(key) ? acc[key].push(i[key]) : acc[key] = [i[key]]);
   return acc;
},{});

// take the key and last item from the values
var result = Object.entries(intermediate).map( entry => {
   var [key,value] = entry;
   return {[key]: value[value.length-1]};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: const onChange = (e) => {
    setSplit(
      Object.entries(
        [
          ...split,
          {
            [e.target.name]:
              0.01 * payment.paymentAmount * e.target.value * 0.2,
          },
        ].reduce((acc, i) => {
          Object.keys(i).forEach((key) =>
            acc.hasOwnProperty(key)
              ? acc[key].push(i[key])
              : (acc[key] = [i[key]])
          );
          return acc;
        }, {})
      ).map((entry) => {
        var [key, value] = entry;
        return { [key]: value[value.length - 1] };
      })
    )
  }

Answer (score 0):

A backwards loop could do the job, storing user names and last-indexes in a separate dictionary. You loop the array from right to left. If the user is not already in the dictionary (i.e., it is its last entry), it adds it in the dictionary; else it just goes on looping.

I recommend to store each entry this way to make looping easier:

```
{ userName: 'mickey gray',
  value: 500 }
```

The loop could be this:

```
let indexDictionary = {};
for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(!indexDictionary[array[i].userName]) {
    indexDictionary[array[i].userName] = array[i].value;
  }
}
```